# whenever i use the intersect boolean tool(not modifier)it makes most of my creation disappear and only leaves the place which was cut out

Tags: modeling, mesh

i am currently doing the blender launchpad course from cgboost and there is a step that requires me to use the boolean tool(not modifier)to make the wheen arches on a car, whenever i use the tool it cuts out the geometry like normal but deletes everything else other than the cut out geometry, i need help trying to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Difficult to tell from your description and image, but it sounds as if you are selecting the objects in the wrong order before using the Boolean addon tool. Select the cutter first, then SHIFT select the object you want to cut and then use CTRL NUMPAD - to produce the cutout.

Comment: The boolean modifier has 2 operation modes. The old *fast* and the new *exact* mode which is default nowadays but it can cause issues. Have you tried the *fast* mode?